# React create and download file from buffer array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, email-parsing

I have an email attachment file in buffer format I want to display and download the file in ReactJS.

Sample JSON

```
{
   "type": "Buffer",
   "data": [137,80,78,71,13,10,26]
}
```

I want to download files in ReactJs or NodeJs.

Comment: What is the format of the file? What will provide the file? Some REST API service or is it stored on some web address? Pls. post your code, what you tried, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 4):

```
const nodeJSBuffer = {
   "type": "Buffer",
   "data": [137,80,78,71,13,10,26]
}

const buffer = Buffer.from(nodeJSBuffer);
const blob = new Blob([buffer]);
                           
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = url;
a.download = "filename.pdf";
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

Comment: if you want to stay on the same page when you download a file : add              
`a.target = '_self';`

Comment: You could also just use the `save-file` package and pass the blob to `saveSync(blob, 'filename.ext')`